# android ip neigh

Tags: android

android で　同一ネットワーク内のIPアドレス（ホスト名がbetrer）を検索しＭＡＣアドレスを調べたいと考えています。

windowsのarpコマンドと同様のことがip neighでできると聞いたのですが、ip neighで表示されるアドレスが安定しません。

192.168.1.1のルーターは常に表示されるのですが、それ以外の端末は表示されたりされなかったり。なぜなのでしょうか？

それ以外の端末とは、ブルーレイレコーダ、LinuxPC、Windows7PCです。

Comment: Android は Linux OS を元にしているので、おそらく `/proc/net/arp` が ARP table になっているかと思います。`cat /proc/net/arp` を実行して表示される内容も同様に、ルータ以外の機器のエントリが表示されたりされなかったりするのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
見てみたのですが、どうやらip neighとcat /proc/net/arp　の内容は一致するようです。朝から数度試したのですが、どちらもルーターのみしか表示されません。
ちなみにandoidOSは4.1.2です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ip neighbour show`は(IPv4に限って言えば)ARPテーブルを表示しているだけです。

ARPテーブルはLAN内の端末がいつも登録されているわけではなく、(おおざっぱに言うと)自分と何らかの通信をしたときに始めて登録されます。

登録されていない端末があれば、たとえばpingでも打てば登録されるでしょう(どちら向きでも可)。

Comment: ubuntu PCからandroid端末にpingを打ち、android端末でip neighを実施したところ、ubuntu PCのip addressが表示されました。

android端末からLAN内に有る端末のip addressを調査したいと考えているのですが、その場合は、適当にネットワーク内のアドレスにpingを打つという事前準備が必要になるのでしょうか？

それ以外には何か方法は有るのでしょうか？